# website deployement using git giving 500 internel server error

Tags: git

I know this is not a new issue on stackoverflow but i havn't found any answer that able to solve this issue for me. So Please help me to solve my issue.

I can see the pushed files in my site directory. however when i try to browse the domain it shows me 500 internal server error. Can you help me?

I Did this so far
on server in public_html folder:

mkdir  test.git

cd !$

git init --bare --shared

chgrp -R developers .

chmod -R g+swX .

vi hooks/post-receive

.....Added on vi editor........

GIT_WORK_TREE = /home/public_html/my2 git checkout -f

chmod +x hooks/post-receive

Then on server in public_html i created another directory as work tree
mkdir my2

cd my2

chgrp -R developers .

### So far all good

On my local machine
i can do the push easily to test.git and the work tree (the my2 folder ) showing me the files too.

The only issue is that when i try to browse my2 on browser i.e. example.com/my2

It is giving me 500 internal server error.

I understand this is the permission isssue. but how to solve it i don't know.

I already see that the user and group change under my2 directory when i do push. i.e.
if i push index.php to test.git

the file permissions change to

-rw-r--r--  1 bharat   bharat       72 Nov 21 10:01 index.php

where bharat is the username who do push to test.git

Please help 
Thanks

Comment: This is not necessarily a permissions issue. The server could be misconfigured. What do your server's error logs say is the cause?

Comment: There is no error coming for this in error logs. BTW i think its correct that its checkout to work tree as user "bharat" thats why its show "bharat" as user and group. but this way its showing 500 internel server error.